# how to make dbms_scheduler.create_job configurable?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

Rather than hard-coding values dbms_scheduler.create_job repaeat_interval, i'd like to make it configurable. Therefore, I have created a new table that allows the repeat_interval from the job to be configured.

Procedure below takes the column as input parameters:

```
    PROCEDURE scheduled_job IS
      v_start_date swpurge_job_config.start_date%TYPE;
      v_freq       swpurge_job_config.freq%TYPE;
      v_byday      swpurge_job_config.byday%TYPE;
      v_byhour     swpurge_job_config.byhour%TYPE;
      v_byminute   swpurge_job_config.byminute%TYPE;
      v_bysecond   swpurge_job_config.bysecond%TYPE;
      v_end_date   swpurge_job_config.end_date%TYPE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT start_date
            ,freq
            ,byday
            ,byhour
            ,byminute
            ,bysecond
            ,end_date
        INTO v_start_date
            ,v_freq
            ,v_byday
            ,v_byhour
            ,v_byminute
            ,v_bysecond
            ,v_end_date
        FROM swpurge_job_config;
      dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'Purge_MW_Log_Data'
                               ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
                               ,job_action      => 'DBA_UTILS_OWNER.PURGE_TABLES'
                               ,start_date      => 'SYSTIMESTAMP'
                               ,repeat_interval => 'freq' || '=' ||
                                                   v_freq || '; ' ||
                                                   'byday' || '=' ||
                                                   v_byday || '; ' ||
                                                   'byhour' || '=' ||
                                                   v_byhour || '; ' ||
                                                   'byminute' || '=' ||
                                                   v_byminute || '; ' ||
                                                   'bysecond' || '=' ||
                                                   v_bysecond || ';'
                               ,end_date        => NULL
                               ,enabled         => TRUE
                               ,auto_drop       => FALSE
                               ,comments        => 'runs weekly and looks for partitions that needs to be purged');

   END scheduled_job;
```

Not sure how else to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

**error messages:**

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "DBA_UTILS_OWNER.SWPURGE", line 450 > "dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'Purge_MW_Log_Data'"

Comment: What does it mean, "it is wrong"? Looks pretty to me.

Comment: @Littlefoot i get a PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_JOB'

Comment: Check JOB_ACTION. Unless I'm wrong, it has to be enclosed into single quotes, so it would be something like `job_action => chr(39) || job_config.job_action || chr(39)`

Comment: @Littlefoot still the same error...

Comment: Well, you'll have to debug it. Go parameter-by-parameter. For beginning, use all "constants" (type those values manually). Then use JOB_CONFIG.JOB_NAME as a parameter and leave the rest as they were - run the procedure, see the result. If it is OK, move on to JOB_CONFIG.JOB_TYPE (so now you'll have two parameters from your table), run it, check the result. And so forth, until you find the culprit (or more of them).

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the table definition. However the 'enabled' parameter of create_job is of type BOOLEAN and since you can't have a column in your table of type BOOLEAN I would suspect that.

Comment: @Littlefoot - i have now editedthe initial question and added new code snippet. I think making the repeat_interval configurable makes more sense. I still get errors with concatenating. Please help me out here...

Comment: I'm sorry but it looks to me like you are trying to re-invent the wheel.  Why not just create some schedules, then assign a job to whatever schedule you want?

Comment: @j_deany The current code has two syntax errors.  The JOB_NAME must be a valid schema object name; you may want to change `Purge MW Log Data` to `Purge_MW_Log_Data`.  And `v_bysecond ''` should probably be `v_bysecond || ';'`.  Try those changes, edit the question, run it again, and post the precise error message.  The calendar syntax is very difficult, breaking it into pieces is going to be complicated.  I understand the desire to not hard-code, but storing each piece of the syntax individually feels like soft-coding to me.  The syntax cannot always be stored in pieces.

Comment: @JonHeller I made the changes but got some errors, please check the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   PROCEDURE scheduled_job IS
      v_start_date swpurge_job_config.start_date%TYPE;
      v_freq       swpurge_job_config.freq%TYPE;
      v_byday      swpurge_job_config.byday%TYPE;
      v_byhour     swpurge_job_config.byhour%TYPE;
      v_byminute   swpurge_job_config.byminute%TYPE;
      v_bysecond   swpurge_job_config.bysecond%TYPE;
      --v_end_date   swpurge_job_config.end_date%TYPE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT start_date
            ,freq
            ,byday
            ,byhour
            ,byminute
            ,bysecond
           -- ,end_date
        INTO v_start_date
            ,v_freq
            ,v_byday
            ,v_byhour
            ,v_byminute
            ,v_bysecond
         --   ,v_end_date
        FROM swpurge_job_config;
      dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'Purge_MW_Log_Data'
                               ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
                               ,job_action      => 'OWNER.PROCEDURE'
                               ,start_date      => v_start_date
                               ,repeat_interval => 'freq' || '=' ||
                                                   v_freq || '; ' ||
                                                   'byday' || '=' ||
                                                   v_byday || '; ' ||
                                                   'byhour' || '=' ||
                                                   v_byhour || '; ' ||
                                                   'byminute' || '=' ||
                                                   v_byminute || '; ' ||
                                                   'bysecond' || '=' ||
                                                   v_bysecond || ';'
                               ,end_date        => NULL
                               ,enabled         => TRUE
                               ,auto_drop       => FALSE
                               ,comments        => 'something');

   END scheduled_job;

BEGIN

   scheduled_job();
END;
/
```

Issue was the single quotes around start_date. Another important thing to note is v_end_date is not allowed to be parsed in as a parameter in the dbms_scheduler (not sure why) however, this is good enough for me.